# JMETER Last HTTP Response access

Tags: regex, jmeter, post-processor

There doesn't appear to be a way to access the latest HTTP Response? I've had to create a REGEXP extractor as a bean postprocessor to HTTP requests in order to store the LAST_RESPONSE then extract it from the vars as needs be?

I feel like I've missed something fundamental along the line wrt to the context/scope of the response...

I understand it's a load testing tool but I've found it to be fairly useful for automation jobs as well.

thanks,
Mark.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-extract-data-files-jmeter) you might want to add `^` character to represent line start so regular expression would look like:

```
(?s)(^.*)
```

If you want to go the [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) you can achieve the same with the following code:

```
vars.put("LAST_RESPONSE", new String(data));
```

where:

- `vars` - shortcut to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which gives read/write access to all JMeter Variables in scope
- `data` - [byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) array which contains parent sampler response

---

In both cases you will get `${LAST_RESPONSE}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which will be holding parent sampler response data.

Comment: Uugh Dmitri, that's exactly the answer, why didn't I think of that?